# A vector bundle $(E, B, \pi)$. Let $S(E)=\{a\in E\mid \langle a,a\rangle=1\}$. Prove that $E-B$ is homotopic to $S(E)$.

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, homotopy-theory, vector-bundles, submanifold

> Suppose $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$ is a Riemannian metric on a vector bundle $(E, B, \pi)$. Let $S(E)=\{a\in E\mid \langle a,a\rangle =1\}$. Prove that $E-B$ is homotopic to $S(E)$.

I am learning the concepts of vector bundle and Riemannian metric. For the problem, I want to first show that $S(E)$ is a submanifold of $E$. Since $S(E)$ is compact, the topological embbedding part is simple. I have some difficulty of prove the submersion part and cannot figure how to go on.

Appreciate any hint or help!

Comment: Can you show that $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^{n-1}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes. By setting $f:S^{n-1}\to \Bbb R^{n}\setminus \{0\}$ ,  $f(x)=x$
and $g:\Bbb R^n\setminus \{0\}\to S^{n-1}$ ,$g(x)=\dfrac{x}{\|x\|}$. But I still don't know how to write the submanifold proof or the original problem.

Comment: The homotopy equivalence in the question is just the "fiberwise" version of the equivalence for $S^{n-1}\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$. (Presumably by $E-B$ you mean $E-Z$ where $Z$ is the image of the zero section.)

Comment: Oh, I think I have understood you idea and now working on writing the rigid proof. Could you also show me how to prove $S(E)$ is a submanifold of E? Thanks very much.

Comment: Use a local trivialization: By choosing an local orthonormal frame on a neighborhood $U\subset M$, you get a trivialization $\pi^{-1}(U)\mapsto U\times\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the inner product on each fiber corresponds to the standard dot product on $\mathbb{R}^n$.